# Is the invariant distribution of the underdamped Langevin equation the Bolztmann distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, stochastic-processes

Essentially what the question asks. I've seen proofs that in the overdamped limit, Langevin dynamics relaxes distributions to the Boltzmann distribution in the $t \to \infty$ limit; but what happens when the assumption of overdamping is relaxed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to go to phase space. I’ll assume that you are referring to the system:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x&=p\\
\dot p&=-V’(x)-\gamma p+\sqrt{2\gamma T}\eta
\end{align}
$$
with $\eta$ a gaussian white noise, i.e. satisfying:
$$
\langle \eta(t)\eta(t’)\rangle =\delta(t-t’)
$$
The overdamped limit is obtained when $\gamma\to \infty$ which becomes:
$$
\gamma\dot x=-V’(x)+\sqrt{2\gamma T}\eta
$$

You just need to write the master equation (Fokker-Planck) of the distribution $\rho(x,p)$ in the general case:
$$
\partial_t\rho=-\partial_x(p\rho)-\partial_p[(-V’(x)-\gamma p )\rho]+\partial_p^2(\gamma T\rho)
$$

In this case, you can check that the Boltzman distribution is a stationary distribution using:
$$
\rho \propto \exp\left(-\frac{p^2/2+V(x)}{T}\right)
$$
In fact, it is an equilibrium distribution (satisfying detailed balance). Furthermore, the result still holds even if you add a matrix diffusion as long as you add the corresponding damping term given by the fluctuation dissipation theorem.

Hope this helps.